# material and flex layout atrributes doesn't work by loading dynamically and works as simple HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I create app using typescript. Now I am in trouble. Template loaded using API from server doesn't work as it was working when it was loaded as part of website on page load. I still can not get whether it is problem because of it is not compiled or because of security reasons. I tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/8397456) example, but it still doesn't work. Here is how I applied the later to my app:

Short description: router calls PageComponentLoader which calls AppService which calls PageComponent (didn't included as it works well, so supposed there are no problems). The later calls API and inserts (sanitizes too) the *answer* to template.

Problem: buttons render as it were `<button>`, but not `<button md-button>MATERIAL</button>`. `div`s render as it weren't `flex`'ed too.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: 'Page/:param', component: PageComponentLoader },
),

declarations: [AppComponent, DclWrapper, PageComponent, PageComponentLoader],
entryComponents: [PageComponent,PageComponentLoader],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

**dynamic.componets.loader.ts** (taken from example from the link)

```
// Helper component to add dynamic components

import { Component, ViewChild, Input, ViewContainerRef, Type, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Compiler } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
    selector: 'dcl-wrapper',
    template: `<div #target></div>`
    //  ,entryComponents: [PageComponent]
})
export class DclWrapper {
    @ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target: ViewContainerRef;
    @Input() types: Type<Component>;
    cmpRef: ComponentRef<Component>;
    private isViewInitialized: boolean = false;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private compiler: Compiler) { }

    updateComponent() {
        if (!this.isViewInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.cmpRef) {
            // when the `type` input changes we destroy a previously 
            // created component before creating the new one
            this.cmpRef.destroy();
        }

        let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.types);
        this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory)
        // to access the created instance use
        // this.compRef.instance.someProperty = 'someValue';
        // this.compRef.instance.someOutput.subscribe(val => doSomething());
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.updateComponent();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.isViewInitialized = true;
        this.updateComponent();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.cmpRef) {
            this.cmpRef.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';    
@Injectable()
export class AppService {    
    component = {
        title: 'Example',
        type: PageComponent
    }    
    getComponent() {
        return this.component;
    }
}
```

**Page.component.loader.ts**

```
@Component({    
    template: '<dcl-wrapper [types]="component.type"></dcl-wrapper>',
    selector: 'Page',
    providers:[AppService]      
})

export class PageComponentLoader 
    component: {};    
    constructor(
        private _appService: AppService) {
    }    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.component = this._appService.getComponent();
    }    
}
```

**page.html**

```
<div fxLayout="column">
    <div [sanitizer]="myPage"></div>         
</div>
```